# Strange error with NSTimer (I believe)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer, void

I'm making an app where I use an `NSTimer` to make a loop. When the app starts, in `viewDidAppear` I check if a certain value in `NSUserDefaults` is set, and if it's not I show the user an `UIAlertView` with an `UITextView`. Until here all ok. Once the user sets the user defaults value, the alert view's `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` calls a `void` that makes the timer work:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:nameField.text forKey:@"host"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    [self setUp];
    NSLog(@"called");
}
```

This is `[self setUp]`;

```
-(void)setUp {


    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 1  target: self selector: @selector(reloadData) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer: timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self reloadData];
    self.host = [self getHostName:val];
    self.ip = [self getHostIP:val];
    NSLog(@"reached here"); //THIS GETS CALLED SO I THINK IT WORKS


}
```

This is `[self reloadData]`:

```
- (void)reloadData {
    NSArray *words = nil;
    words = [[self getUptime] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    //int sum = [[words objectAtIndex:0] intValue] / 100.0;
    float sum1 = ([[words objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / 10.0);
    NSLog(@"%f", sum1);
    [bar1 setProgress:sum1];
    load1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [bar1 progress]];

    float sum2 = ([[words objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] / 10.0);
    NSLog(@"%f", sum2);
    [bar2 setProgress:sum2];
    load2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [bar2 progress]];


    float sum3 = ([[words objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] / 10.0);
    NSLog(@"%f", sum3);
    [bar3 setProgress:sum3];
    load3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [bar3 progress]];

}
```

The problem is that the tableView cells doesn't get the values and remains white, but if you close the app and load it again (when it has the variable in the user defaults) the thing works perfectly so I don't know what could happen. I also get so often `wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003`in the log (I know this happens when you don't call the superview)

Comment: also the NSTimer:scheduledTimerWith... messages auto-schedule a timer, saves a line of code, and every line of code saved is... uh, offsets your carbon footprint by ... uh... anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duh, I found the problem. I was using the variable `val` which was set on app start, and it was empty when the user defaults didn't had that key :/ so I just did: `NSString *userhost = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"host"];` when calling the `setUp` void after dismissing the alert view

Answer (score 0):

Do you call [table reloadData]? It's odd that you named your own internal function the same as the tableview's message.

Comment: when I want the table view to reload the data I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` and for my function is `[self reloadData]`. I can change them, if that can be a problem

Comment: No, not a problem, just unusual.